# PostgreSQL. Is such function vulnerable to SQL injection or is it safe?

Tags: postgresql, sql-injection

### Functions that looks problematic

I'm exploring postgresql database and I see a recurring pattern:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION paginated_class(_orderby text DEFAULT NULL, _limit int DEFAULT 10, _offset int DEFAULT 0)
RETURNS SETOF pg_class
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
BEGIN
        return  query  execute'
            select * from pg_class
        order by '|| coalesce (_orderby, 'relname ASC') ||'
        limit $1 offset $1
        '
        USING _limit, _offset;
END;
$$;
```

Sample usage:

```sql
SELECT * FROM paginated_class(_orderby:='reltype DESC, relowner ASC ')
```

Repeating is:

- `_orderby` is passed as `text`. It could be any combination of fields of returned SETOF type. E.g. `'relname ASC, reltype DESC'`
- `_orderby` parameter is not sanitized or checked in any way
- `_limit` and `_offset` are integers

DB Fiddle for that: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vF6bCN37yDrjBiTEsdEwX6/1

### Question: is such function vulnerable to SQL injection or not?

By external signs it's possible to suspect that such function is vulnerable to sql injection.

But all my attempts to find combination of params failed.

E.g.

```sql
CREATE TABLE T(id int);
SELECT * FROM paginated_class(_orderby:='reltype; DROP TABLE T; SELECT * FROM pg_class');
```

will return **"Query Error: error: cannot open multi-query plan as cursor"**.

I did not found a way to exploit vulnerability if it exists with `UPDATE`/`INSERT`/`DELETE`.

So can we conclude that such function is actually safe?

If so: then why?

### UPDATE. Possible plan for attack

Maybe I was not clear: I'm not asking about general guidelines but for experimental exploit of vulnerability or proof that such exploit is not possible.

DB Fiddle for this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vF6bCN37yDrjBiTEsdEwX6/4 (or you can provide other of course)

My conclusions so far

#### A. Such attack could be possible if  `_orderby` will have parts:

1. sql code that suppresses output of first `SELECT`
2. do something harmful
3. `select * from pg_class` so that it satisfies `RETURNS SETOF pg_class`

E.g.

```sql
SELECT * FROM paginated_class(_orderby:='relname; DELETE FROM my_table; SELECT * FROM pg_class')
```

It's easy for 2 and 3. I don't know a way to do 1st part.

This will generate: **"error: cannot open multi-query plan as cursor"**

#### B. If it's not possible to suppress first `SELECT`

Then:

- every postgresql function works in separate transaction
- because of error this transaction will be rollbacked
- there is no autonomous transactions as in Oracle
- for non-transactional ops: I know only about sequence-related ops
- everything else be that DML or DDL is transactional

So? Can we conclude that such function is actually safe?

Or I'm missing something?

### UPDATE 2. Attack using prepared function

From answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69189090/1168212

A. It's possible to implement Denial-of-service attack putting expensive calculation

B. Side-effects:

> If you put a function with side effects into the ORDER BY clause, you may also be able to modify data.

Let's try the latter:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION harmful_fn()
RETURNS bool
LANGUAGE SQL
AS '
DELETE FROM my_table;
SELECT true;
';

SELECT * FROM paginated_class(_orderby:='harmful_fn()', _limit:=1);
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vF6bCN37yDrjBiTEsdEwX6/8

Yes.

So if an attacker has right to create functions: non-DOS attack is possible  too.

I accept Laurenz Albe answer but: is it possible to do non-DOS attack without function?

Ideas?

Comment: A rule of thumb is that if the user can pass in arbitrary text that gets interpreted as code, then you have a potential SQL injections and is therefore not safe. You always need to clean user input data.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman The question is not about general guidelines but how to exploit such vulnerability. Can you provide an example how to exploit such vulnerability?

Comment: I understand. What I meant was to answer the question you posted whether it's safe or not. If a user can pass in arbitrary text that gets interpreted as code, then it's not safe, no matter what. Even if you can't find a vulnerability. Even if you prove that no such exist, it's still not safe, as it's a hole that can potentially open up sooner or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not safe. An attacker could put any code into your `ORDER BY` clause via the `_orderby` parameter.

For example, you can pass an arbitrary subquery, as long as it returns only a single row: `(SELECT max(i) FROM generate_series(1, 100000000000000) AS i)`. That can easily be used for a denial-of-service attack, if the query is expensive enough. Or, like with this example, you can cause a (brief) out-of-space condition with temporary files.

If you put a function with side effects into the `ORDER BY` clause, you may also be able to modify data.

Comment: Can you show an example how to exploit  this vulnerability? Because I did not found a way to do something harmful

Comment: Did you get an error with the method you suggested? It is easy to do harm by calling a function with side effects in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vF6bCN37yDrjBiTEsdEwX6/5  . I conclude that " error: cannot open multi-query plan as cursor" will result in rollback. So it's easy to pass something harmful but it will be rollbacked

Comment: Hm. You gave me a thought: even if it's not possible to corrupt data - it should be possible to slow down postgresql instance.

Comment: I have added possible exploits to the answer.

Comment: You're correct: if harmful actions are enveloped in a function, this function could be called in `ORDER BY` clause. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vF6bCN37yDrjBiTEsdEwX6/7. So attacker must have rights for `CREATE FUNCTION`. Interesting: is it possible to do not-DOS attack without prepared function?

Comment: Perhaps. Depends on the existing functions. And just if you cannot think of an exploit right away, that doesn't mean that the attacker cannot. Do the right thing and use `format()` or `quote_literal()` to escape the string, and your headache is gone.

Comment: Of course. The whole question was to estimate severity of problem and how urgent we need to fix those functions. `quote_literal()` will not be enough to sanitize input such as `field1 ASC, field2 DESC nulls first` but that's another topic